# How to install Windows Azure SDK for Java

Tags: java, windows, azure

I have a problem. I can't install windows azure sdk for java in eclipse. I download sdk and plugin from " http://www.windowsazure4e.org/update " and " http://dl.windowsazure.com/eclipse ". But when i build project, the compiler generates an error "BUILD FAILED
C:\Users.........\AzureTest\package.xml:94: Windows Azure SDK is not installed."
Why? Help me please....

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse Plugin for windows azure needs windows azure SDK for packaging and also for providing various runtime libraries.

Install latest windows azure eclipse plugin from http://dl.msopentech.com/eclipse
 and the plugin will prompt you to install the SDK when you try to create windows azure project.

Answer (score 0):

you should change workspace path from "C:Users//.../AzureTest/" to "C:/workspace/AzureTest".
After this, recompile and try to create package.

Please paste full log message.

Comment: Buildfile: C:\workspace\AzureTest\package.xml

createwapackage:
        [exec] Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\workspace\AzureTest\emulatorTools\ResetEmulator.cmd" (in directory "C:\workspace\AzureTest"): CreateProcess error=2, ?? ??????? ????? ????????? ????
      [delete] Deleting directory C:\workspace\AzureTest\deploy
       [mkdir] Created dir: C:\workspace\AzureTest\deploy

BUILD FAILED
C:\workspace\AzureTest\package.xml:94: Windows Azure SDK is not installed.

Total time: 320 milliseconds

Comment: Please check below tasks
 1. install Windows Azure Emulator(you should install it by Web PI)
 2. check program paths in RunInEmulator.cmd and ResetEmulator.cmd

Answer (score 0):

WindowsAzure4e is really out-of-date. Take a look at the [Java developer page](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/java/) on the Windows Azure portal and get the instructions for the new stuff released in December, specifically [Installing the Windows Azure SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh690944%28VS.103%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The source code of Windows Azure SDK for Java is available on github https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-java

However, if you just want to use it in your maven project, you can simply reference it in the pom file, maven will take care of the rest.

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/java/java-home/download-for-linux/